# Best Way To Create Multi Column Page on CakePhp

Tags: php, css, cakephp

I want to create a multi column page. I am not sure about which way I should prefer for adapting myself to cakephp's coding discipline.

Should I create columns on my view//index.ctp or on layouts/default.ctp

If layouts/default.ctp is the sutiable way, how can I fetch the other content? As you know, there is  a line for fetching controller's view content like `<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>` How can I fetch another content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply declare a block somewhere else, in your view file for example, use start() and stop() to define a block and output it with fetch(). For example start('menu'); and then calling fetch('menu') will display the content between the start and stop call.

Read this:

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#extending-views
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#view-blocks
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#displaying-blocks

Comment: Thank you for answer burzum . Actually I am not clear about where and how would I define the content for my column. For example there is "sidebar" content on your links. It fetchs the sidebar content with `<?php echo $this->fetch('sidebar'); ?>` but where did it be defined?